# OSM changes not getting to MapBox?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I can't be the only one to have noticed this, can I?

For about a month now, changes made in OSM have not been appearing on Mapbox maps.

For example, changeset http://www.openstreetmap.org/changeset/45041984 (23 days ago) has not appeared on any mapbox style, v6 to v9.

Another good example is changeset http://www.openstreetmap.org/changeset/45457434 where I added/edited a few businesses. Only 8 days ago, but easier to see because there are icons.

I'm not imagining things, there's something wrong, isn't there?

Answer (score 1):

An answer! I pestered a Mapbox contact directly on their OSM user account, and got the following response:

> Hi Andrew, that is right, we have stopped syncing live from OSM while
>   we upgrade our data processing pipeline. We're testing the live sync
>   again and things should be back to normal within a week if all goes well :)

Delighted to have a response. Rather annoyed that it took so long, and so many attempts to get it!